# Get string between two specific characters in unix

Tags: unix, sed

I need to get string between 2nd # to .(dot) using unix command.
For ex string is `TEST#CV01#170403053938.csv`
output should be `170403053938`

Can some one please advice how to get.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
A="TEST#CV01#170403053938.csv"
B=${A##*#}
echo ${B%%.*}
```

I am simply using parameter expansion to get the exact required values here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$ echo "TEST#CV01#170403053938.csv"|egrep -o '[[:digit:]]{10,20}'
170403053938
```

OR

```
$ echo "TEST#CV01#170403053938.csv"|awk -F'[#.]' '{print $3}'
170403053938
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be done with [`sed`](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) (might be overkill), but for the sake of regex!

```
 echo "TEST#CV01#170403053938.csv"|\
    sed -e 's/\(.*#.*#\)\(.*\)\(\.csv\)/\2/'
```